# How do I find a number which when divided by 4, 5, 6 and 7 gives 3, 4, 5 and 6 as remainders respectively?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic, puzzle

Is there specific set of steps to be followed when solving similar questions?

**My attempt:**

A number gives remainder 3 when divided by 4. Hence it is of the form **4m+3** where m = 0,1,2…

Now, 4m+3 gives remainder 4 when divided by 5. It means (4m+3)-4 is divisible by 5.

Hence, 4m-1=5n where n is some positive integer. **n=(4m-1)/5**.

But, 4m+3 gives remainder 5 when divided by 6. It means (4m+3)-5 is divisible by 6.

Hence, 4m-2=6f where f is some positive integer. **f=(4m-2)/6**.

Again, 4m+3 gives remainder 6 when divided by 7. It means (4m+3)-6 is divisible by 7.

Hence, 4m-3=7l where l is some positive integer. **l=(4m-3)/7**.

**My confusion:** What do I do now? Or am I even in the right path?

**Please don't solve it using modular arithmetic. I don't know it yet.**

Comment: This is a repeated direct application of the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  This is a special case however that should be straightforward to solve.  Notice that $3=4-1$ that $4=5-1$, that $5=6-1$ etc... so you are looking for a number which satisfies $\begin{cases}n\equiv -1\pmod{4}\\n\equiv -1\pmod{5}\\n\equiv -1\pmod{6}\\n\equiv -1\pmod{7}\end{cases}$.  A clear candidate would be $-1$.  If you want it to be positive, then consider adding $\text{lcm}(4,5,6,7)$.

Comment: "*Please don't solve using modular arithmetic*"  There is no time like the present to learn.  It works just like ordinary arithmetic with most of the same rules that you are already familiar with, just requiring a little bit more abstraction.  All you need to know about it can be learned in 2 minutes.

Comment: " Please don't solve it using modular arithmetic. I don't know it yet." Then learn it.  It's exceedingly easy and will be much easier to learn it a solve this using modular arithmetic then to solve it any other way.  There is no reason it should take anyone more than a half hour to learn modular arithmetic.

Comment: Okay..    @JMoravitz

Comment: Ok, going to give a shot  @fleablood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a$ be your number. Then note that $a + 1$ divided by $4, 5, 6 \text{ and } 7$ will give remainders of $0$ in all cases. Thus, the smallest positive $a + 1$ will be the smallest number which $4, 5, 6 \text{ and } 7$ all divide into. Since $6$ and $4$ each have a factor of $2$, you don't need to repeat this factor, giving it to be $4 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 420$, giving that $a = 419$ works.

Note that, in general, $a = 420n - 1$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: Beautiful, elegant solution! Perfectly aligns with JMoravitz's comment on modular arithmetic, and adding the lcm to the mod

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Thanks for the compliment. I tried to keep it quite simple based on my perception of the OP's limited math knowledge, such as the request to not using modular arithmetic. Similarly, I chose to not explicitly mention the lcm for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution is a lot simpler than I have thought.  :)

Comment: @salsabil.raisa You are welcome. Quite often there's some little trick with these sorts of problems that makes them fairly easy to solve.